# Why compiler says Works cannot be resolved to a type?

Tags: java, generics, types

I just want to declare a generic type for simple things but the compiler get errors that type is not resolved!
this is how i did in main:

```
//Main and Works are in same file
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Works<Integer> a = new Works<Integer>();   //this line got problem
        a.add(2);
        a.add(0);
        a.add(15);
        a.add(-8);
        a.add(6);
        System.out.println(a.getMin());
    }
}
```

and this is my class declaration
`

```
//generic class declaration
class Works<T extends Comparable> {
    private ArrayList<T> works = new ArrayList<T>();

    public void add(T item) {
        works.add(item);
    }

    public T getMin() throws IllegalStateException {
        if (works.size() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Your task table is empty");
        }
        T tmp = Collections.min(works);
        remove(tmp);
        return tmp;
    }

    public Comparable[] getLess(T element, boolean remove) {
        Collections.sort(works);
        if (remove) {
            remove(element);
        }
        return works.subList(0, works.indexOf(element)).toArray();
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Are classes `Main` and `Works` in the same package? If not, did you use the correct import?

Comment: Yes they are... they are even in same file

Comment: @Mahdi you cannot have two public classes in the same file.

Comment: @StephenC actually they are in same file. this won't work as same package?

Comment: @Henry I checked it too but this error exists yet

Comment: Could you post the whole file instead of chunks when it's all in a single file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is your package structure.

If they are in different package, then you have to import the class.

For example :

Create `Main` class in package `com.example` and `Works` class in `com.example.demo` :

```
package com.example;

import com.example.demo.Works;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Works<Integer> a = new Works<Integer>();   //this line got problem
        a.add(2);
        a.add(0);
        a.add(15);
        a.add(-8);
        a.add(6);
        System.out.println(a.getMin());
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.example.demo;

//generic class declaration
public class Works<T extends Comparable> {
    private ArrayList<T> works = new ArrayList<T>();

    public void add(T item) {
        works.add(item);
    }

    public T getMin() throws IllegalStateException {
        if (works.size() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Your task table is empty");
        }
        T tmp = Collections.min(works);
        remove(tmp);
        return tmp;
    }

    public Comparable[] getLess(T element, boolean remove) {
        Collections.sort(works);
        if (remove) {
            remove(element);
        }
        return works.subList(0, works.indexOf(element)).toArray();
    }
}
```

If you want to keep `Works` class in same package. then define the `Works` with default scope in `Main.java` like this below :

```
package com.example;

//generic class declaration
class Works<T extends Comparable> {
    private ArrayList<T> works = new ArrayList<T>();

    public void add(T item) {
        works.add(item);
    }

    public T getMin() throws IllegalStateException {
        if (works.size() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Your task table is empty");
        }
        T tmp = Collections.min(works);
        remove(tmp);
        return tmp;
    }

    public Comparable[] getLess(T element, boolean remove) {
        Collections.sort(works);
        if (remove) {
            remove(element);
        }
        return works.subList(0, works.indexOf(element)).toArray();
    }
}    

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Works<Integer> a = new Works<Integer>();   //this line got problem
        a.add(2);
        a.add(0);
        a.add(15);
        a.add(-8);
        a.add(6);
        System.out.println(a.getMin());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make them separate classes. (Main and Workers each in one class

If you want separate classes for those, you may want to put `main` method into a class declaration. Something around

### *Works.java*

```
public class Works {
    // Works class declarations
}
```

### *Main.java*

```
// If it's in the same folder/package you don't need to import Works
public class Main {
    // main method here
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Also, let say you want to put both in a different folder/package, you'll need to add package statement to define which folder the class is in relative to the class that have a main method in it.

#### For example:

Works location:

1)  `PROJECT_FOLDER/workstuff/Works.java`

- You will need to declare `package workstuff;`

Class with main method location:

1) `PROJECT_FOLDER/Main.java`

- You won't need to declare package statement since it's in root folder

2) `PROJECT_FOLDER/somepackage/Main.java`

- You'll need to declare `package somepackage;`

As for both Main class cases, you'll need to `import workstuff.Works`